# how print local timezone in posix format in java(android)?

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, posix

i want somehow to print local timezone in EEE 1003.1 (POSIX) format.
in a form:

```
 std offset dst [offset],start[/time],end[/time]
```

described at http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

i had figured out how to get the `std` and the `offset` from `TimeZone` java object, I can even get the `start` and `end` of the DST from the timezone object using reflection or parsing the `toString` output... What I cannot figure out is how to get the `dst` field, which is The `dst` string and offset specify the name and offset for the corresponding     Daylight Saving Time zone, which not the same as `std offset`, for example this is correct for Eastern time zone in the United States:

```
EST+5EDT,M4.1.0/2,M10.5.0/2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat and format a fitting date with the template `z`. If I read the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), especially the examples, correctly that should result into the abbreviated form of the DST name